# Auto submit Excel print forms

Tags: excel, vba, printing

TLDR: Can I auto submit print dialog with VBA?

I have an Excel table with products data with columns [numberOfCopies, name, size, weight, price] - max 30 products (30 rows for different items).

I have a VBA macro copies data from that table to other, special "Label" spreadsheet, selects area and opens print dialog box to print as many copies as I want.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:D7").Select
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show , , , numberOfCopies, , , , , , , , 1
```

As it works right now:

- I press "Print All" button that fires macro
- For each table row:
- It checks if there are product information in row
- If yes: copy data to label and open xlDialogPrint

The effect is i need to press 1 button, and then press enter X times, 1 time for each row, to submit print dialog. Is there a way to auto submit dialog box, so I just press 1 button?

Comment: Maybe try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.printout instead

Comment: How exactly will it help me?

Comment: It will print directly, without the dialog.

Comment: Ok, i will check it, thanks.